# Как найти среднее арифметическое всех элементов массива?

Tags: java

Например:

```
int[] numbers = {5, 8, 12, -18, -54, 84, -35, 17, 37};
```

Как найти среднее?
Какой алгоритм, или может есть специальные функции для этого?

Comment: Вот сделать бы из этого вопроса FAQ - было бы полезно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сам алгоритм, который работает для всех версий Java:

```
// среднее арифметическое - сумма всех чисел деленная на их количество
int[] numbers = {5, 8, 12, -18, -54, 84, -35, 17, 37};

double average = 0;
if (numbers.length > 0)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
         sum += numbers[j];
    }
    average = sum / numbers.length;
}
```

Comment: Добавил исправление

Answer (score 5):

Ну [например](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

```
IntStream.of(numbers).average();
```

Это Java 8, stream API. Проверка: http://ideone.com/hSng8I

Comment: Feel the power of LINQ!

Comment: джаву же просили

Comment: @danpetruk: А это что? http://ideone.com/hSng8I

Comment: @danpetruk: На C# выглядит несколько проще: http://ideone.com/IoowuC, т. к. массив является сам stream'ом.

Comment: Хм. А почему тогда "Feel the power of LINQ!"? LINQ это же C#. Вот я и подумал, что код сишарпный

Comment: @danpetruk: Ну, потому что stream API немного _похоже_ на LINQ.

Answer (score 4):

```
OptionalDouble average = Arrays.stream(numbers).average();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class average {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int num [] = {5, 8, 12, -18, -54, 84, -35, 17, 37};
        double sum = 0;
        for (int x: num) {
        sum += x;
        }
            System.out.print("среднее арифметическое чисел равно: " + sum/num.length);
    }
}
```